# How do I safely JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JSON.stringify on a string that contains `<script>`-tags and somehow the script tags escape and end up in the body of my document, producing horrible results of "injected" data.

I don't understand how they can escape, the quotation marks etc. are escaped through JSON.stringify. I've also tried JSON2.stringify to no avail.

Comment: How are we supposed to debug code we can't see?

Comment: The accepted answerer was able to do it within 9 minutes of me posing the question so I think there was enough information available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the JSON string as code (i.e. an object literal), you have to take care of the script tags to keep them from breaking out.

The script tags are parsed as HTML before the Javascript inside it is parsed, so it doesn't matter that the script tag is inside a string in the code, it will still be seen by the HTML parser. This isn't specific to JSON strings, this happens whenever you put a script tag in a string in Javascript code.

You can put extra characters in the script tags to prevent them being parsed as HTML tags, for example making them `<scr\ipt>` or `<scr"+"ipt>`.

Comment: or convert the `<` and `>` to html entities :) here's a [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/)

Comment: What do you call those kind of encodings? (&bnsp; etc.)

Comment: @Willem: That's an HTML entity. To escape those in a string is called HTML encoding.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks, I'll look into HTML encoding. It seems like the most straightforward and correct way to solve it.